# How to extract a column (or a row) of a matrix as another column vector/ column matrix (or a row vector), not as a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix 'mat' as

```
mat = Table[Subscript[m, i, j], {i, 5}, {j, 5}];
mat // MatrixForm
```

I want to extract the first column (or any row) as

```
a = mat[[All, 1]]
```

```
{Subscript[m, 1, 1], Subscript[m, 2, 1], Subscript[m, 3, 1], \
Subscript[m, 4, 1], Subscript[m, 5, 1]}
```

But I want the output as

```
{{Subscript[m, 1, 1]}, {Subscript[m, 2, 1]}, {Subscript[m, 3, 
  1]}, {Subscript[m, 4, 1]}, {Subscript[m, 5, 1]}}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Note that in MMA a distinction between row and column vectors is not necessary. The reason for this is, that the dot product is cleverly defined as the contraction of the last index of the left hand side by the first index of the right hand side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = mat[[All, {1}]]
```

> ```
> {{Subscript[m, 1, 1]}, {Subscript[m, 2, 1]}, {Subscript[m, 3, 1]},
>   {Subscript[m, 4, 1]}, {Subscript[m, 5, 1]}}
> ```

```
MatrixForm  @ a
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try `Partition[mat[[All, 1]], 1]`.